# change rectangle size according to the data in Prefuse

Tags: swing, prefuse

I  want to visualize a scatter plot using Prefuse. The difference from typical scatter plot is here I want to use rectangle instead of circle or point. And the reason is I want to visualize the time and duration at the same time. Does anyone know how to set rectangle's length or width according to data in the table? I haven't got the right answer after searching the web.

I initially wants to draw rectangle using this parameter.

```
    ShapeAction shape = new ShapeAction(group, Constants.SHAPE_RECTANGLE);
```

But I didn't find the way to change only the length of it but to change the whole size. Could anyone give me some instructions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to create a visualization similar to [LifeLines](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/lifelines/) or a GANTT chart.

To achive this, prefuse has to be extended prefuse on several points. Here is an outline:

1. Add a field to the `VisualTable` to store the x coordinate at the end of the rectangle
2. Extend `AxisLayout` to determine the additionally the end of the rectangle.
3. Extend `AbstractShapeRenderer` draw a rectangle using the end coordinate